# Asking DCG Prolog for an answer

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

I have a DCG written in prolog which tries to translate a string into simple propositional logic.

The current rules are:
  + means OR, * means AND, - means NOT

```
g(or(X,Y)) -->
    f(X),
    "+",
    g(Y).
g(X) -->
    f(X).

f(and(X,Y)) -->
   e(X),
   "*",
   f(Y).
f(X) -->
   e(X).

e(not(X)) -->
   "-",
   d(X).
e(X) -->
   d(X).

d(X)-->
   "(",
   g(X),
   ")".    
d(a)-->
   "a".
d(b)-->
   "b".
```

However I am having problems with `Out of local trace` errors.

This code should be correct, but how do I ask Prolog to give `and(not(or(a,b)),or(b,not(a)))` as an answer to `-(a+b) * (b + -a)`

Comment: You can use your grammar to generate all sentences like so:  `?- length(L,N), phrase(g(X), L).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your grammar seems fine, but you forgot to handle/skip blanks

```
?- phrase(g(X), `-(a+b)*(b+-a)`).
X = and(not(or(a, b)), or(b, not(a))) ;
false.
```

(note: I've manually removed all blanks, and used SWI-Prolog extensions for list of codes literal.)

Comment: ?- phrase(g(X), `-(a+b)*(b+-a)`).
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: phrase(g(X), `-(a+b)*(
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: b+-a)`) .

Comment: Which extensions did you use?

Comment: I mean the backticks around the input - you can see them in my post... otherwise, use `?- atom_codes('-(a+b)*(b+-a)',Cs), phrase(g(X), Cs).`

Comment: @JoséValente: please note that using <code>\`</code>  is SWI specific. All other systems either reject this or interpret this differently. Thus: `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).` and use `"` for `phrase/2`. This works everywhere.